# Need to animate the size of the child of a FractionallySizedBox

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm playing with some theories on how to approach a layout. The simple version is that I have a `Container` and I'm allowing its size to be determined by its parent `FractionallySizedBox`. On orientation change *(calculated intentionally)*, the size calculated by the `FractionallySizedBox` changes correctly but it's instantaneous, not animated.

I would like it to animate the size change, but please realize that AnimatedSize won't work the way I need because its behavior is actually more like an Animated Clipper. The child of the AnimatedSize actually changes instantly, it's the AnimatedSize that animates its size to reveal more or less of the child as it animates. This is not the desired behavior. I'm looking to zoom in and out.

The reason the orientation is calculated is this is intended to work on all platforms, and desktops and web don't report an orientation afaik. But by comparing height to width, I can determine which is wider, width or height.

Thanks for any help with getting the size to zoom in and out.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Adaptive Layouts',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: AdaptiveRotationTest(title: 'Adaptive Rotation Test'),
    );
  }
}

class AdaptiveRotationTest extends StatelessWidget {
  AdaptiveRotationTest({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  double screenHeight;
  double screenWidth;
  double borderWidth;
  bool isPortrait;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    borderWidth = min(screenWidth, screenHeight) * 0.02;
    isPortrait = screenHeight > screenWidth ? true : false;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Adaptive Rotation Test'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(borderWidth),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedAlign(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                alignment: Alignment(
                  isPortrait == true ? -0.9 : 0.9,
                  isPortrait == true ? -0.9 : 0.9,
                ),
                ///
                /// Need to animate the size, without knowing the size since it's calculated as heightFactor and widthFactor.
                /// Also, AnimatedSize behaves more like an AnimatedClipper over a Container that changes size instantly, which
                /// is not what we're going for. We're looking to zoom in or out.
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                  heightFactor: isPortrait == true ? 0.3 : 0.5,
                  widthFactor: .5,
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    color: isPortrait == true ? Colors.purple : Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How would the animation looks like?

Comment: maybe a custom `ScaleTransition`?

Comment: @Remi what I'm going for here is a box that animates its position, color and rotation based on the fake orientation, which I'm getting from the MediaQueries. The idea is that this should be platform-independent and a lot of platforms, and some phones such as the foldable, don't report orientation.

Normally this would just be an AnimatedContainer, but I have no set size to give it because I use a FractionallySizedBox to set its size. But now I need to animate the size of the Container, which means animating the size of the FractionallySizedBox.

Comment: @pskink ScaleTransition looks workable but I was hoping for something more simple to implement, something that wouldn't require logic to trigger an animation. But for now, ScaleTransition looks like the most promising solution.

Comment: Then in @pskink's name - at least up vote his comment :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated class for it now:
[AnimatedFractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedFractionallySizedBox-class.html)

Usage from the docs:

```
child: AnimatedFractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: selected ? 0.25 : 0.75,
          heightFactor: selected ? 0.75 : 0.25,
          alignment: selected ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.bottomRight,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: const ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: FlutterLogo(size: 75),
          ),
        ),
```

Actually missed it myself and implemented something else